# SQL Server : select from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table **Accounts**:

```
+----+------+----------+
| ID | Nick | Dono_CID |
+----+------+----------+
|  2 | Bart |        3 |
+----+------+----------+
```

Table **Logins**:

```
+------------+------------+
| Jogador_ID | TS_Logou   |
+------------+------------+
|          2 | 1590116475 |
|          2 | 1590118258 |
+------------+------------+
```

In short, I intend to identify if there is a row with TS_Logou smaller than the Timestamp of 1 month ago, and if Dono_CID != -1

OBS: `Accounts.ID = Logins.Jogador_ID`

OBS²: There are multiple records in the Logins table. I want to select the last one, in DESC order

My attempt:

```
SELECT 
    ct.Nick, 
    ct.Dono_CID 
FROM 
    Contas AS ct 
INNER JOIN 
    Logins AS lg ON lg.Jogador_ID = ct.ID 
WHERE 
    ct.Dono_CID != -1 
    AND lg.TS_Logou < 1587524400 
GROUP BY 
    lg.Jogador_ID 
ORDER BY 
    lg.TS_Logou DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What is the datatype of TS_Logou ?  how is the value derived ? can you please put the DDL of Player table ?

Comment: The value is a timestamp value, it records the time of the player's last login.

Comment: do you mean the timestamp datatype, which is currently deprecated in favour of rowversion ?

Comment: Yes, I want to make two queries in one, the first, if exists rows in the Logins table ```WHERE TS_Logou > x```, and the second, ```WHERE Dono_CID != -1```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` is MySQL stuff - not supported by SQL Server - you'll need to do `SELECT TOP (1) ...`

Answer (score 0):

From your attempt, I understand that TS_Logou < 1587524400, means older than one month.
I am trying to select the login with the maximum TS_Logou satisfying the filter condition.

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 a.Id, a.Nick, a.Dono_CID
FROM Logins as l
Inner Join Account as a
a.Id = l.Jogador_Id 
WHERE a.Dono_CID <> -1 
AND a.TS_Logou < 1587524400
ORDER BY l.TS_Logou DESC
```

Comment: Correcting: ```SELECT TOP 1 a.Id, a.Nick, a.Dono_CID
FROM Accounts as a
Inner Join Logins as l
WHERE a.Id = l.Jogador_Id 
AND a.Dono_CID <> -1 
AND l.TS_Logou < 1587524400
ORDER BY l.TS_Logou DESC```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your SQL: ```'1 a.Id, a.Nick, a.Dono_CID
FROM Accounts as a
Inner Join Logins as l
WHERE a.' na linha 1```

Comment: How do I query the number of rows found with one query within another? So I can make a SELECT if there are rows in Logins for the current month, and if they don't, consult if ```Dono_CID != -1```

Comment: @PedroHenrique, what syntax error, I did not get. for your requirement, you can use EXISTS clause in the WHERE clause

Comment: `AND EXISTS ( select * from logins WHERE TS_Logou > 1587524400 and Jogador_Id = l.Jogador_id)` -- Checking whether login exists for past one month

Comment: With this condition the server is in an infinite loop, and nothing results

Answer (score 0):

in hear, I try to select max TS_Logou form Logins for the user and that table joins with the Account table. this works for me

```
SELECT 
 ac.Nick, 
 ac.Dono_CID 
FROM 
    Account AS ac 
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT l.Jogador_ID,MAX(l.TS_Logou) FROM Logins AS l 
   WHERE DATE(l.TS_Logou) < DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) 
   GROUP BY l.Jogador_ID) AS lg 
 ON lg.Jogador_ID = ac.ID 
WHERE 
 ac.Dono_CID <> -1
```

Comment: I got the list, but all returned players have a login record this month (after the specified timestamp)